# SQLi and retreiving a specific record

Tags: php, mysqli

looked around, saw a lot of MySQL answers but not MySQLi..
Im attempting to return 1 line of my choosing.
at the moment I can return only the first line.

What im trying to get to is, have my main database be linked by ID, when you click the ID, a closer look at the record is on another page..

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
$query = "SELECT name, surname FROM info ORDER BY id";
$record = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
@$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($record);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record);

$fname = $row['name'];
$surname  = $row['surname'];

print $fname;
print $surname;



?>
```

Comment: Well assuming you want `id` 2 then `SELECT name, surname FROM info WHERE id=2`

Comment: Jeez, that was simple..
Hmm okay so keep in mind im a beginner..
if I wanted to make my table have each ID be a link, and when you click the ID you go to the record page.. the way I would code that would be...
to turn id= Variable?

Comment: Don't use `@` while developing, that just hides useful errors from you. Also you need to use `fetch` in a `while` if you want more than 1 record. `where` is how to limit the results of a query, and if using a variable parameterize the query. `SELECT name, surname FROM info WHERE id= ?` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver and chris85 
any advice on my second question?

Comment: `SELECT name, surname FROM info WHERE id= ?` is the actual query. See the link I provided, you bind the `GET` parameter.

Comment: oh wow, I get ya now. thanks chris!!!

Comment: Guys sorry to bother again, getting a bit confused.. I get the query but..
how do I create this variable that will take x variable from my table and use it on another page..
how does ? = a specific 'x'
what am I echoing?

Comment: The page here is the page being loaded from the link, or the page the link should be built on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you're asking, first create a list of users:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
$query = "SELECT name, surname FROM info ORDER BY id";
$record = mysqli_query($query, $connect);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record)){
    $user = $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['surname'];
    echo '<a href="user.php?uid=' . $row['id'] . '">' .$user . '</a></br>';
}
```

The will create a list of all your users which look like:

```
<a href="user.php?uid=1">Bart Simpson</a></br>
<a href="user.php?uid=2">Matt Damon</a></br>
```

And so on.

When you click the user's link in the original page, it should be processed by the code in user.php:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
$query = "SELECT name, surname FROM info WHERE id = ?"; // returns one line identified by id - you can use something else if you're guarateed the value is unique in your table
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $_GET['uid']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name, $surname);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

I'll bet you can guess what happens now, can't you? That's right, you can echo out the data for the individual user on this page:

```
$user = $name . ' ' . $surname;
echo $user;
```

NOTES:

1. The connection code could be placed in a separate file and included in pages where needed.
2. You could write a function to handle every query you write.
3. In order to prevent the possibility of SQL Injection I have used [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!
4. Generally I would be a lot more consistent with my coding, performing queries the same way each and every time. doing so will reduce troubleshooting time as well as making your code easier for others to read.

Comment: Awesome stuff @Jay Blanchard 

But the way I made my database is that so other people can come in and leave a new record.
so me making a list of < a href links to my different users isn't applicable right?

one page will be an ever changing database
the other page will be a zoom in of a record.

does your explanation above cover this as well?

Comment: Yes, it sure does.

Comment: hmm okay so, I put your second block of code on its own user.php... as well as the echo call right under it... Back on my main I added your code, expecting to get IDs in link formation... but now im getting the ol "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects paramer 1 to be mysqli_result, Boolean given" Error..

Comment: You need to add error checking to the code to make sure you're connecting to the database properly before running the query. I made a mistake by not changing `mysqli_query(0` when I copied your code. The query comes first, then the connection.

Comment: sorry, my beginner understanding it acting up again.  
my connection should be fine, it worked before with my code above. 
The only thing I changed would be getting rid of everything after my @ and pasting in your While.

Comment: FORGET IT! I made a typo! the links work. 
now I have to figure out user.php as im getting errors.

Comment: well one, you used GET uid, did you mean id?... and me error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'  
... my echo is... echo '$user = $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['surname']';

Comment: No - it is `uid` because that is what I placed in the URL. You should `echo $user;` *after the last line of my code above. I'll edit @Charlesx54321

Comment: Awesome! now 3 new errors ;D.... all of the 3 lines... mysqli_stmt_bind, mysqli_stment_execute, mysqli_fetch_array are All getting errors... the first 2 "expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt" and the 3rd "expects parameter 1 to be "mysqli_result"

Comment: OK - now check errors in your connection, because those errors indicate a problem with the query and since the query is good it has to be the connection.

Comment: wait, @Jay, shouldn't we be adding the $connect somewhere?

Comment: Oooops, my bad. I typed all of this out when I wrote the answer and I forgot the `prepare()`. I have updated the code again. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: did a little if statement to check connect and check mysqli select db, and neither came back negative.

Comment: Ok, we're almost there ;D... mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: that's exactly what I changed before asking, but I got the same error!

Comment: OK - this is one of the reasons I build functions to do things. MySQLi requires so much more verbosity than PDO and I forgot everything (binding results, fetching, preparing....all.the.things) when I typed out this answer. The code above is fully tested :) Please note all of the changes. I'm so sorry for being an idiot @Charlesx54321

Comment: Beautiful @Jay, working great!
thank you for taking all of this time to help me!!! appreciate it greatly!!

Comment: Glad to help and brush up at the same time @Charlesx54321